# Check if the front end user is log in or not

Tags: wordpress, plugins, authentication

I am using "front-end-only-users" plugin for user registration and log in system. Now how i check that my front end user is log in or not through coding i use 'is_user_logged_in()' but it checking the admin panel user.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
}
```

OR Try this

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
if ($current_user->ID == '') { 
    //show nothing to user
}
else { 
    //write code to show menu here
}
```

Comment: are you using in fron end ? did you checked both cases (logged in , logged out)

Comment: my user is login and after this "<? if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?> 
                     <a href="<?=post_permalink( 47 )?>" class="arb">Logout</a>
                    <? } ?>" the logout link still not appearing.

Comment: $current_user->ID give me 0 if user login or logout.

Comment: if $current_user->ID is blank or zero then user loggedout  otherwiser loggedin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81250/discussion-between-nasir-and-sarath).